# Detect onLongPress and onClick event in onTouchListener

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I have an `onTouchListener()` where I need to determine whether user clicked or long pressed.
So I can determine it's a simple click or it's a long click, but the problem is that I can to determine it is only in `Motion.ACTION_UP`.

```
mViewBinder.actionMain.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private long lastTouchDown;
        private int CLICK_ACTION_THRESHOLD = 200;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    lastTouchDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTouchDown < CLICK_ACTION_THRESHOLD) 
                        Logger.log("OnCLickEvent", "onClickListener");
                    else 
                        Logger.log("OnCLickEvent", "onLongClickListener");

                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I think I need to determine somehow in `ACTION_DOWN`, whether it is a long press and in `ACTION_UP` determine it was a click. My purpose is to show a toast when
1) user long pressed the button without pulling out his finger
2) user clicked the button

I think you understand. So I use `OnTouchListener()`, because I need that `MotionEvent event` in constructor for my future purposes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your use case. If there is a reason you can't just use setOnLongClickListener(),
I'd suggest using a GestureDetector instead.

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector

Comment: It didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

### you can use GestureDetector for it

```
new GestureDetector(context,
                    new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: It didn't help.